# is JMeter support Browserstack Mobileapp Performance testing

Tags: jmeter

I have a requirement, there is Browserstack web application login from there we can upload APK file and launch Mobile app using any of the Android device. We have to login mobile app and do other transactions in mobile app.

Jmeter will support to do performance testing for Browserstack Mobileapp Performance testing or any other tool support to do Browserstack Mobileapp Performance testing  ?

Please provide your inputs

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

JMeter acts on a [network protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lists_of_network_protocols) level, it cannot conduct mobile application performance testing.

What JMeter can do is to mimic mobile applications network footprint so you can simulate hundreds or even thousands of mobile users concurrently using the application to stress the [backend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frontend_and_backend) (or the database). If this is what you're looking for check out [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/mobile-app-load-testing) article to learn more about the concept.

If you're looking for the tool other than Browserstack to measure CPU usage, battery usage, code efficiency and so on - consider using [The Android Profiler](https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/android-profiler)